# How to calculate damping ratio and natural frequency of a high order system?

Tags: transfer-function, laplace-transform

To calculate the rate of damping and the natural frequency of second-order systems is easy, third order as well. How do I calculate the damping rate, natural frequency, overshoot for systems of order greater than 3?

In other words, if each pole has a damping rate and a natural frequency, how can the damping rate and natural frequency resulting be found.

For example, the system: 
$$
f(s) = s^5 + 13s^4 + 100s^3 + 1300s^2\;?
$$

Comment: \$\zeta \approx 0.01 \times PM\$ gives the damping coefficient for the ‘equivalent’ standard 2nd order TF. But the parameters you are looking for do not really apply to anything other than a standard 2nd order.

Comment: Why bother trying to calculate when you can use a bunch of free sim tools such as micro-cap?

Comment: I wonder if 20log(H(s) of this function viewed as a Fourier spectrum gives you an idea of the harmonic content for a sine or step input. Can you imagine how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Systems that are higher order are composed of smaller poles, so you can find the dominant poles (I'd use a bode plot and find the peaks, if any) to find the natural frequency. As far as I know, there is no damping ratio for higher order systems (it is dependent on the smaller order systems). Overshoot is best found by simulating (with a step input).

Do a partial faction decomposition and look at the resultant second (complex) or first order systems.